# Amazon Linux2 の iptables を起動時に反映する方法

Tags: linux, amazon-linux, iptables, systemd

AWS EC2 で iptables を叩くだけでは再起動時に毎回リセットされてしまうので
再起動しても反映されるようにしたいのですが
Amazon Linux2 の場合どこに何を設定するのが普通なのでしょうか

他の Linux だと
/etc/sysconfig/iptables にコマンドを書いて
`sudo systemctl enable iptables`
でいいみたいなんですが Amazon Linux2 だと iptables コマンド自体はあるのですが
`Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory`
となってしまいます

---

AWS inspector の結果

`rule 3.5.1.2 Ensure loopback traffic is configured`

という項目に違反していて

```
Rationale


Loopback traffic is generated between processes on machine and is typically critical to operation of the system. The loopback interface is the only place that loopback network (127.0.0.0/8) traffic should be seen, all other interfaces should ignore traffic on this network as an anti-spoofing measure.

Run the following commands to implement the loopback rules:
                # iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
                # iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
                # iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

を行うためです

Comment: 参考: "Amazon EC2ではセキュリティグループを使って簡単にファイアウォールの設定を行うことができるので、iptablesやfirewalldを使うことはあまりありません。" - https://www.bit-hive.com/articles/20190807

Comment: 実用上はそうなんですがセキュリティ要件で AWS inspector の HIGH 以上が存在しないことをエビデンスに出す必要があって、その中に iptables が動いてないという項目が high で存在しているのでやむなく対応しなければいけなくなった次第です

Comment: 関連サイトでの類似質問: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/225319/298771